A question about the rational function expansion
I have a question about  the rational function expansion.
There is a power series $\sum_{m\ge 0}{a_mu^{2m}}$, where $a_0\ne 0$ and $a_m\in\mathbb{C}$.
Moreover, there also exists $f(u)\in \mathbb{C}[u]$ and $g(u)\in \mathbb{C}[u]$ such that
$$\sum_{m\ge 0}{a_mu^{2m}}=\dfrac{f(u)}{g(u)}.$$
Can we get that there exists $f_1(u),g_1(u)\in \mathbb{C}[u]$, such that $\sum_{m\ge 0}{a_mu^{m}}=\dfrac{f_1(u)}{g_1(u)}$?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

both even, or both odd, if $f$ and $g$ don't share common factor, see : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548985/if-a-rational-function-is-even-then-the-numerator-and-the-denominator-have-same
